# XML Deserialize to List of Custom objects

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to Deserialize a XML string that comes from an webrequest and I am having trouble adding it into a List of custom objects that I can iterate through, I've just spent 2 hours around this and I just can't figure out what am I doing wrong, this is the first time I am trying something similar so at this point I am a bit clueless.

**So here is the XML that I am trying to Deserialize:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<school_search>
  <summary>
    <total_schools>5</total_schools>
    <category>private</category>
  </summary>
  <schools>
    <school>
      <school_id>12</school_id>
      <school_name>School of Literature</school_name>
    </school>
    <school>
      <school_id>31</school_id>
      <school_name>School of Sports</school_name>
    </school>
    <school>
      <school_id>38</school_id>
      <school_name>School of Arts</school_name>
    </school> 
    <school>
      <school_id>40</school_id>
      <school_name>School of Science</school_name>
    </school>
    <school>
      <school_id>43</school_id>
      <school_name>School of Business</school_name>
    </school>
  </schools>
</school_search>
```

**This is the classes I've created to deal with this specific XML:**

```vb
<XmlRoot(ElementName:="school_search")>
    Public Class xmlSchool_search
        <XmlElement(ElementName:="summary")>
        Public Property Summary() As xmlSummary
            Get
                Return m_Summary
            End Get
            Set
                m_Summary = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Summary As xmlSummary
        <XmlElement(ElementName:="schools")>
        Public Property Schools() As xmlSchools
            Get
                Return m_Schools
            End Get
            Set
                m_Schools = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Schools As xmlSchools
    End Class

    <XmlRoot(ElementName:="schools")>
    Public Class xmlSchools
        <XmlElement(ElementName:="school")>
        Public Property School() As List(Of xmlSchool)
            Get
                Return m_School
            End Get
            Set
                m_School = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_School As List(Of xmlSchool)
    End Class

    <XmlRoot(ElementName:="summary")>
    Public Class xmlSummary
        <XmlElement(ElementName:="total_Schools")>
        Public Property Total_schools() As String
            Get
                Return m_Total_schools
            End Get
            Set
                m_Total_schools = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Total_schools As String

        <XmlElement(ElementName:="category")>
        Public Property Category() As String
            Get
                Return m_Category
            End Get
            Set
                m_Category = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Category As String

    End Class

    <XmlRoot(ElementName:="school")>
    Public Class xmlSchool
        <XmlElement(ElementName:="school_id")>
        Public Property School_id() As String
            Get
                Return m_School_id
            End Get
            Set
                m_School_id = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_School_id As String

        <XmlElement(ElementName:="school_name")>
        Public Property School_name() As String
            Get
                Return m_School_name
            End Get
            Set
                m_School_name = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_School_name As String

    End Class
```

**This is the relevant code to deserialize the xml into my custom class:**

```vb
   request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)
   response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

   Dim schoolsList As List(Of xmlSchool)
   Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
         Dim deserializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of xmlSchool)), New XmlRootAttribute("schools"))
         schoolsList = DirectCast(deserializer.Deserialize(reader), List(Of xmlSchool))
   End Using
```

**And finally this is what I use to iterate through it:**

```vb
 For Each school As xmlSchool In schoolsList
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(school.School_id)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br/>")
 Next
```

**The Problem:**
I always get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <school_search xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

I've tried to change the XmlRootAttribute to school_search and it doesn't throw an exception, however the schoolList is empty, I believe the problem lies within the custom classes but I just can't see where is the issue.

Thank you all in advance for taking your time looking into this problem.

Comment: When posting anything containing XML, please be careful and make sure all XML is code-formatted (either in backticks or as a block indented 4 spaces).  If you don't do that your tags will be silently discarded and not appear in the rendered question.  I fixed the exception message.

Comment: I am sorry about that Jim, thank you for the edit!

Comment: All part of the learning process, and unfortunately it is not immediately obvious what SO markdown does with `<` in text.  As a rule, if you post anything with XML be sure to look at the preview to make sure it looks how you expect.  BTW, nicely written question. I'd upvote but I'm out of votes for today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `xmlSchools` class, you can introduce collection of schools as property of type `List<of xmlSchool>` in `xmlSchool_search` class.
Then use `XmlArray` attribute to tell serializer that current property represents a collection.

```vb
<XmlRoot(ElementName:="school_search")>
Public Class xmlSchool_search
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="summary")>
    Public Property Summary As xmlSummary

    <XmlArray(ElementName:="schools")>
    Public Property Schools As List(Of xmlSchool)
End Class

<XmlType(ElementName:="summary")>
Public Class xmlSummary
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="total_schools")>
    Public Property Total_schools As String

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="category")>
    Public Property Category As String
End Class

<XmlType(ElementName:="school")>
Public Class xmlSchool
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="school_id")>
    Public Property School_id As String

    <XmlElement(ElementName:="school_name")>
    Public Property School_name As String
End Class
```

Deserialization

```vb
Dim deserializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(xmlSchool_search))
Dim search As xmlSchool_search = Nothing

Using reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
     search = DirectCast(deserializer.Deserialize(reader), xmlSchool_search )
End Using

Dim schools As List(Of xmlSchool) = search.Schools
```

Because you have no custom logic in the properties setters and getters you can use property shorthand

```vb
Public Property Name As String
```

Comment: Thank you, that was spot on! It all makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

I like to parse simple xml with xml linq

```vb
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim search As Search = doc.Descendants("school_search").Select(Function(x) New Search() With { _
                                                                           .total_schools = x.Descendants("total_schools").FirstOrDefault(), _
                                                                           .category = x.Descendants("category").FirstOrDefault(), _
                                                                           .schools = x.Descendants("school").Select(Function(y) New School With { _
                                                                                                                         .name = y.Element("school_name"), _
                                                                                                                         .id = y.Element("school_id") _
                                                                                                                                         }).ToList()
                                                                       }).FirstOrDefault()
    End Sub

End Module
Public Class Search
    Public total_schools As Integer
    Public category As String
    Public schools As List(Of School)
End Class
Public Class School
    Public name As String
    Public id As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it seems to me a very clean solution. The reason I accepted the previous answer as the correct instead of your solution its because I am not used to LINQ but I will definitely take a closer look at it the next time I have to go through .NET, so thank you for this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Often xml files have extra level that are not needed.  Serialization you have to have the classes match the xml file.  With manual parsing you can often eliminate layer like I eliminated summary.